# unbound method operate() must be called with instance as first argument

Tags: python, list, class, object

I am trying to go through a list of class objects in my program, and access functions belonging to the objects.

I am using this method :

```
# - - - Grid Updating

def update_grid(self):

    for i in range(len(self.populationList)):
        self.populationList[i].operate
```

To access this object type :

```
class Dotian():

    goal = '#'
    log = []
    position = (0,0)

    def __init__(self):

        self.name = ops.randomLine('data/names')

    def operate(self):
        print 'here'
```

The list is populated like so :

```
# - - - Spawning Dotian

def spawn_dotian(self):

    coord = ops.randomCoordinates(0, self.width-1)

    if self.grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] == 0 :
        spawnDot = Dotian
        spawnDot.position = coord
        self.populationList.append(spawnDot)
        self.grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] = 1
    else :
        self.spawn_dotian()
```

The program should print `here` but it doesn't print anything.

Using python 2.7.3

Comment: Class objects? I think you mean "instances of class Dotian".

Comment: To make in instance of a class, do "spawnDot = Dotian()". To call a method on that instance, do "spawnDot.operate()".

Comment: If you look, you can see that I do that. then I do `self.populationList.append(spawnDot) `  I need to call it from self.populationList.

Comment: Do you see the brackets in my comment?

Comment: Seriously? after each code line in my 2nd comment ;)

Comment: If I change `self.populationList[i].operate` to `print self.populationList[i].goal` I am able to access the Dotian's goal variable. Is accessing the methods in this manner not possible ?

Comment: If you do that, it will print the string representation of the bound method object. In python, functions/methods are objects too. You can pass them around to higher level function for example. So, no, if you want to execute the function you have use the call operator "()" after the function name.